# How to clip a portion of waveform and pull it to zero level?

Tags: comparator, voltage-clipping

I've generated a sawtooth waveform of 5v and i want to allow 1.5v to 2.5 v and rest of the voltage should be detected as zero. I tried using clipper but it didnt get desired result. Is there any circuit which works like window clipper? How do i get the above result?

Comment: It sounds like you might be interested in using a combination of a clipper circuit and a [Schmitt Trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger). Just to clarify, do you want the circuit to set 2.5 -> 5V to 0?  Or are you trying to clamp the Voltage from 0 -> 2.5 V ?

Comment: Why not post a picture of what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is a circuit to solve your problem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0o9Wd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and here is what the simulated output looks like:
[image]
Where blue is the input sawtooth signal, and orange is the output signal of the circuit.

If the input voltage is out of the range of 1.5 V to 2.5 V, the output is 0 V, and if the input voltage is between 1.5 V and 2.5 V, Output Voltage = Input Voltage.
Depending on your background in electronics, this circuit may seem pretty convoluted, so here is what is happening in the circuit:
1) R4 and R5 form a voltage divider with an output of 2.5 V
2) R2 and R3 form a voltage divider with an output of 1.5 V
3) OA8 compares the 2.5 V (from 1)) with the input signal, has a high output if the input signal is greater than 2.5 V
4) OA9 compares the 1.5 V (from 2)) with the input signal, has a high output if the input signal is less than 1.5 V
5) If either OA8 or OA9 have a high output signal, M1 and M2 pull the 'processed signal' node to ground.
6) R1 allows M1 and M2 to pull 'processed signal' to ground without damaging the signal source or M1 and M2  by drawing too much current
7) OA2 is an analog buffer, to lower the output impedance.

If anyone knows why the little bump just after 2s on the transient graph is there, please let me know :)

Comment: thank you very much!! This looks like a window comparator. I think that transcient is due to rise and fall time delay.

Comment: can I get a similar waveform at 3V to 4V along with 1.5V to 2.5V simultaneously? Is it possible to chop two portions on a single waveform?